# Drake's mathematical programming framework and it's compatibility with other simulators (MuJoCo)

Tags: drake

I was scoping the task of trying to integrate Drake's mathematical programming (MP) interface with another simulator (say MuJoCo). The primary need here is to use a legacy project simulation setup but also to be able to ask optimization questions around the task. MuJoCo has a nascent implementation of the optimization framework, but I wanted to go with Drake's mature opt pipeline.

In my experience with running the Drake's MP tutorials, it seems that the MP interface is pretty self-contained. I'm guessing the big problem is the supply of gradients that comes from the simulator for any gradient-based optimization.

Out of curiosity, what would be the steps that need to be undertaken to create a bridge between Drake's optimization pipeline and another simulator's `step` function.

Thank you for your help and instruction!

Comment: The strongest applications of optimization to MultibodyPlant dig beneath the `step` interface to exploit more structure in the equations... even beyond simple gradients. We have a MuJoCo parser in Drake (not fully featured yet, but it's easy to fill in any missing pieces). Would loading the mjcf into Drake's MultibodyPlant work for your workflow?

Comment: If you _do_ want to use a block-box chunk of code, then the path forward would be to write a custom cost and/or constraint which called out to your other codebase.  But it's true that most of our optimizers do require gradients.

Comment: So an additional step would be to write a "gradient" bridge between the simulator and the gradients that the drake solvers expect?

Comment: In order to use gradients from the simulator that is. I am still trying to map what would be a worthwhile exercise, to write the bridge, or implement the simulation scenario from scratch in drake. Thank you for your replies.

Comment: That sounds right. You could certainly try finite difference gradients (which is what MuJoCo recommends, I believe), and wrap them into Drake's AutoDiffXd.